# How to make limit offset dynamic using only (My)SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

This code doesn't work

```
select pagenr into @offset from pages where id = 3;
select * from table1 limit @offset*10, 10;
```

What SQLcode do I need to use in order to get this kind of code to work
using **only** SQL!

Note that

```
SET SQL_SELECT_LIMIT = @count
```

doesn't work because I'm mainly concerned with the offset, not the limit as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the MySQL 5.5 specification:

> The `LIMIT` clause can be used to
>   constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the `SELECT` statement. `LIMIT` takes
>   one or two numeric arguments, which
>   must both be nonnegative integer
>   constants, with these exceptions:
>
> - Within prepared statements, `LIMIT` parameters can be specified using `?`
>     placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, `LIMIT` parameters can be specified using 
>     integer-valued routine parameters or local variables as of MySQL 5.5.6.

So, inside a stored procedure, the following would work:

```
DECLARE offset bigint
SELECT pagenr * 10 INTO offset FROM pages where id = 3;
SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT offset, 10;
```

Otherwise, you'll need to precompute the value and pass it in via the query. You should already know the page size and page number, so this shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: Aren't @variable session variables ?

Comment: @peufeu, @variables yes, but Kazelzarath is not using @variables.

Comment: I did edit the example to be more complete. Initially, I was just going off what he's already posted.