# How to use subquery to define Mysql SELECT LIMIT offset?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, limit

I have been trying to define "dynamically" the offset of a query.

But when executing this query I always end up with a `You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

When I do remplace the subquery by a number it does work fine. Is there something wrong in a query that has this shape?

```
SELECT LengthOfStay
FROM table1
LIMIT (SELECT CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT(LengthOfStay)) / 2 AS SIGNED) FROM table1 t1), 2;
```

Ps. I casted it so I can make sure it's an integer.

Comment: Avoid the pain, do two queries mate, even if you succeed IMHO you'r code will be much messier. That's just my opinion :)

Comment: Looks like duplicate [How to make limit offset dynamic using only (My)SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872667/how-to-make-limit-offset-dynamic-using-only-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

You can not use a subquery as a `LIMIT` argument. Limit argument should be an `INTEGER`. Your subquery returns, well... basically, a table.

What are trying to achieve by this query anyway? This query does not make any sense to me...

Answer (score 0):

As @michal points out the answer is in [How to make limit offset dynamic using only (My)SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872667/how-to-make-limit-offset-dynamic-using-only-mysql)

Basically if you're not in a stored procedure or a prepared statement you can't do it.

If you have a stored procedure just assign a variable the value of your "inner" select and use that on the real statement.

If you have a prepared statement use "limit ?, ?" and set the values from the call.