# SQL finding median

Tags: mysql, sql, median

I have a table with a list of 499 positive non-integer numbers N, I want to find the median of these numbers and I have below:

```
SELECT (ROUND(N,4)) FROM TABLE ORDER BY N LIMIT 1 OFFSET ((COUNT(N)-1)/2);
```

I get the following error:

> "ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 15: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '((COUNT(N)-1)/2)' at line 4"

This works if I replace `((COUNT(N)-1)/2)` by **249** (where the median would be after table is ordered), so I can't use `((COUNT(N)-1)/2)`. Why is this? What should I put instead to find the median?

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible to make the LIMIT a dynamic number in a select query see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5873705/2067753

Answer (score 1):

Alas, you cannot include expressions in the `limit`.  You *could* count the number of rows in the table and then pass that in as the limit.

I would normally use:

```
select avg(n)
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from (select t.*
            from t
            order by n
           ) t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
     ) t
where 2 * rn in (@rn - 1, @rn, @rn + 1);
```

Notes:

- The additional level of subqueries is needed in the most recent versions of MySQL -- parameters do not always mix with `order by`.
- The `where` works for both even and odd numbers of rows.
- The `avg()` takes the middle point when the number of rows is even.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complex, you need to creta a index aligned with your data and after catch it

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
(SELECT 
    t.*, @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS rank
FROM
    myTabel t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
ORDER BY ColumnToSort) AS B
WHERE
     B.rank = (SELECT 
             ROUND(COUNT(*) / 2, 0)
        FROM
             myTable)
```

Basically, you want get the row with row number equal of half of selection.
MySql doesn't supports any function that return this value so you need to make yourself.  A very good reference can found here ([MySQL - Get row number on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select))

The main code is behind this few code line:

```
SELECT 
    t.*, @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS rank
FROM
    myTabel t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
ORDER BY ColumnToSort
```