# How to diagnose SQL errors?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm self-learning SQL and after finishing the basics in SQLbolt, I discovered HackerRank and got stuck with [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-20/problem) suing MySQL.

I tried the following code below, but it returns an error:

```
SELECT ROUND(LAT_N,4) FROM STATION
ORDER BY LAT_N DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET (SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(LAT_N)/2) FROM STATION)
```

The error is as follows:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(LAT_N)/2) FROM STATION)' at line 3
```

What seems to be the problem with the code above? The flow of thought supposedly was to sort the `LAT_N` in descending manner and get only one value using `LIMIT`. Now, to get the median, we offset the limit by `(SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(LAT_N)/2) FROM STATION)`. When I only run that query, it returns a value of 249. When I use `OFFSET 249` instead of the subquery, the result is correct. Why does it not work with the subquery?

Also, is there a diagnosis tool in SQL that runs you through the step-by-step process of the code, so you would pinpoint on what step the code is returning an error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make limit offset dynamic using only (My)SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872667/how-to-make-limit-offset-dynamic-using-only-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

It is not allowed to use a sub-query for the values after `LIMIT` or `OFFSET`.

A (clumsy) workaround is shown in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) using [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html).

Something like:

```
SET @a = (SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(LAT_N)/2) FROM STATION);

PREPARE STMT FROM '
   SELECT ROUND(LAT_N,4) FROM STATION
   ORDER BY LAT_N DESC
   LIMIT 1 OFFSET ?';

EXECUTE STMT USING @a;
```