# Alternative for Rand function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Initially, the query was fast but as the rows increased the performance degraded. My table consists of 600K rows and now we face a major performance issue with the Rand() function.

```
SELECT id,postalCode,location 
from jobs_feed 
WHERE check_parsed= 1 AND similarjob_status=0 AND is_updated != 0
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Please explain why you think this is an issue with the RAND function, because I think the issue is with the number of records. (and maybe a missing index?  Can you add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE jobs_feed ` ? )

Comment: Yes, this question has been asked before, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211329/quick-selection-of-a-random-row-from-a-large-table-in-mysql, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast

Comment: Tip:  `is_updated != 0` is not [_sargable_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) .  Change to `is_updated = 1` (if that is the only other value).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL needs to determine a random number of all 600K+ rows, just to determine which row comes first.

A possible work around can be:

```
SELECT id,postalCode,location
FROM (
   SELECT id,postalCode,location 
   from jobs_feed 
   WHERE check_parsed= 1 AND similarjob_status=0 AND is_updated != 0
   ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000 )x
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

This will first select the first 1000 records, and then pick a random row from those.

NOTE: This behavior is different from that you where doing, but faster because only the first 1000 records need to be fetched.

NOTE2: You can change 1000 to another (bigger) value, as long as you think performance is OK (and this alternative way of selecting is OK.)

EDIT: An alternative approach would be to do a dynamic (read RANDOM) offset, like given in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5873705/724039

This should be done in a stored procedure, and would look something like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getRandomRow`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE offset BIGINT;
    SET offset = RAND()*600000; -- change this to get the number of records from your table, and not the fixed 600000
    SELECT id,postalCode,location 
       from jobs_feed 
       WHERE check_parsed= 1 AND similarjob_status=0 AND is_updated != 0
     ORDER BY id LIMIT offset,1;
END
```

Comment: Thanks, Luuk, but I'm looking to fetch a random id from whole 600K records.

Comment: That restricts you to the first (or last) 1000 rows.  It is not practical to use this technique to sometimes get rows from the 'middle' of the table.

Comment: True, that why I wrote the NOTE, because yesterday I did not have enough time to think if one could add a dynamic (=random) OFFSET.  An answer using dynamice OFFSET is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5873705/724039  With some change it could be changed to random OFFSET with a LIMIT of 1 record.

Answer (score 0):

Add a composite index as already discussed, then pick the appropriate algorithm from this set:  [*Random*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random)

Comment: Rick, is this page appropriately closed? I don't see your advice to add a composite index on the other mentioned pages.  Either I am missing something, or this page should be reopened, or your advice should be found on the dupe target.  No?

Comment: @mickmackusa - It would be lost in all the Answers; it's the first Comment on the Question:  `Here's 8 techniques; perhaps one will work well in your case. – 
Rick James
 Jul 5, 2015 at 15:39   `

Comment: Well, I rewrote it to get rid of the inefficient ones -- There are only 5 now in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random

Comment: I scoured this site when I was developing my blog.  Nearly all are inefficient when you have a big table.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't much way to optimize `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`.  But we can try adding the following index to speed up the `WHERE` filter:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON jobs_feed (check_parsed, similarjob_status, is_updated);
```

This index, if used, can potentially allow MySQL to discard many records from the query pipeline, leaving behind only a small subset to randomly shuffle.